# Rails - how do you access a foreign key object in a html.erb template? Works in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning rails by trying to model a collectible card game.

I have a champion model and a rarity model.  I have the has_many/belongs_to in the model definition and this works in the console:

```
c = Champion.find(1)

c.rarity.name
=> "Uncommon"
```

When I do the same thing in a template, I get

```
<%= champion.rarity.name %>

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

This is on Rails 3.2.2.

#### Update: Full .erb code

```
<% @champions.each do |champion| %> 
  <tr> 
    <td><%= champion.name %></td>
    <td><%= champion.rarity.name %></td> 
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If I change the erb to champion.rarity, I get a '#<Rarity:0x007fa3cbf77940>' which seems like it should work.

Comment: `<% @champions.each do |champion| %>
<tr>
 <td><%= champion.name %></td>
 <td><%= champion.rarity.name %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If every `Champion` does not have a `Rarity` association (some are `nil`), you can use a `.try()` to print the name. Otherwise the `.each` will fail with a `NoMethod`  when one without a `Rarity` is encountered.

```
<% @champions.each do |champion| %> 
  <tr> 
    <td><%= h champion.name %></td>
    <td><%= h champion.rarity.try(:name) %></td> 
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Or the less clever `unless nil` method:

```
<% @champions.each do |champion| %> 
  <tr> 
    <td><%= h champion.name %></td>
    <td><%= h champion.rarity.name unless champion.rarity.nil? %></td> 
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

**Note**: I have also added the `h()` helper method to encode these for HTML output, though this is done automatically in Rails 3.